# Java: If(comparing strings to integers)

Tags: java, if-statement

I am currently trying to write a simple input dialog program where user is prompted to enter their name. I want to create an if statement that if user enters any number or special char that the user is then prompted to use characters a-z and asked to re-enter name.
 here is my code so far and I am not sure how to even write the if statement, the error I am getting is incomparable data types Strings and integers.

```
public class inputdialogbox {
   public static void main(String[] args)  {
      Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in);
      String first_name;      
      first_name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your First Name",
         "User's Name",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
      int intValue = Integer.parseInt(first_name);
      if (first_name == intValue);
```

Comment: Did you know about regular expression?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please search for existing similar questions before posting.  If you look at the "Related" links on the right, there are similar results.

Comment: No I did not know about regularexpressions.

Comment: Basically its what you need, sorry for not coding it for you, make some research,

Comment: I am not asking for coding. I just want to understand how to an if statement should work if I am trying to keep the input only in characters between Aa-Zz. Everything else just repeats the dialog box. I have been scouring tutorials on if statements and most examples are used only with integers. nothing with comparing Strings to Integers, and if(string == integer) then return to the previous input screen to do it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex:  `[A-Za-z ]+`

Means

```
[                //Each character must be...
    A-Z          //a capital letter OR
    a-z          //a lower-case letter OR
    __A_SPACE__  //a space
]+               //and there must be between 1 and infinity of these characters
```

Working example:

```
   import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
/**
  <P>{@code java LettersOnlyXmpl}</P>
 **/
public class LettersOnlyXmpl  {
  public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {
     Pattern pLettersOnly = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z ]+");
      test(pLettersOnly, "Obama");
      test(pLettersOnly, "Kermit The Frog");
      test(pLettersOnly, "The QuIcK brown FOx JUMPED over the lazy DOg");
      test(pLettersOnly, "23874298374");
  }
   private static final void test(Pattern p_p, String s_name)  {
      System.out.print(s_name + "...");
      if(p_p.matcher(s_name).matches())  {
         System.out.println("Contains only letters and spaces. Good.");
      }  else  {
         System.out.println("ERROR: Must contain letters and spaces only.");
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Obama...Contains only letters and spaces. Good.
Kermit The Frog...Contains only letters and spaces. Good.
The QuIcK brown FOx JUMPED over the lazy DOg...Contains only letters and spaces. Good.
23874298374...ERROR: Must contain letters and spaces only.
```

Comment: How is Obama considered an error if it contains only the characters specified in "[A-za-z]+

Comment: Would you be able to set "THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG" and in lower case and mix of upper and lower into you code and pass?

Comment: The code is right, the output was from a pre-final version. Sorry about that. Fixed.

Comment: Upper and lowercase is fine. But your original question says "letters", nothing about spaces. Just change `[A-Za-z]+` to [A-Za-z ]+` to add the possibility of spaces.

Comment: I added your quick brown fox and space requirement to the above code.

Comment: Sorry to keep picking your brain but could you explain, and how it is tested. I am extremely new to programming and haven't worked with that class. I want to understand the terms in the test output.

   private static final void test(Pattern p_p, String s_name)  {
      System.out.print(s_name + "...");
      if(p_p.matcher(s_name).matches())  {
         System.out.println("Contains only letters and spaces. Good.");
      }  else  {
         System.out.println("ERROR: Must contain letters only.");
      }
   }
}

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a school.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the question.

Comment: I don't understand what you need to know. It's being implied by a more experienced user than me, that I've given more than enough information to get started with. Study the above, and look at the JavaDoc for specific functions you don't understand. Everything you need to know is there.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn how to use regular expressions, or you can check if the user entered an invalid character. It sounds like what you are trying to do is validate the characters that the user entered, meaning check that all of the characters in the string are in the set of characters from a-z. So why don't you check that the characters are valid rather than invalid and some possible integer type?

Learn about iterating the chars of String with charAt here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_charat.htm

Don't bother converting the string to an integer, just loop the string and check that each character is individually in the allowed list or range.

Comment: Awesome, so what I was doing was trying to set a loopback for each possible input that is not what to be expected?? Not sure if I asked that right. What you are saying to set a predetermined character list before the user is prompted for input?

Comment: The list can be predetermined in many possible ways, something implicit with a for loop, or maybe an array (or string) of the valid characters. Then one data is inputted loop and compare.